# How to get time changed from utc to the chosen timezone in moment.js?

Tags: javascript, datetime, timezone, momentjs, moment-timezone

Let's say I have a date like:

```
"2000-01-01T01:00:00Z"
```

It is in the UTC timezone. I want to move the time to the `Europe/Copenhagen` timezone so that it would be `"2000-01-01T02:00:00"`.

I wanted to use `moment-timezone` to do it. However the problem is that it always uses my local timezone (which is not the `Europe/Copenhagen`). I tried multiple ways, for example:

```
const date = '2000-01-01T01:00:00Z';
return moment(date).tz('Europe/Copenhagen').format('YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss');
```

But still the point of reference is my local timezone. I don't want it to use my local timezone at all. How to achieve it?

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "the point of reference is my local timezone"? The above code returns the string I expect it to, and if you change "Europe/Copenhagen" to "America/Los_Angeles" it returns "1999-12-31T17:00:00" as I'd expect. I'm not sure what you're expecting here vs what you're actually seeing.

Comment: @JonSkeet I'm in the Quatar timezone. The above code returns '2000-01-01T04:00:00' for me (taking into account my local browser timezone). It should return '2000-01-01T02:00:00' (Copenhagen time).

Comment: Okay, so I suspect it's the `moment(date)` part that's not taking the Z into account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried two options.

> The timezone is represented by the 'Z' at the end of the date

First one like you:

```
moment('2000-01-01T01:00:00Z').tz('Europe/Copenhagen').format('YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss');
```

Second one is tricky:

```
moment.tz('2000-01-01T01:00:00Z', 'UTC').tz('Europe/Copenhagen').format('YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss');
```

I get:

```
2000-01-01T02:00:00
```

With the two options. What's the version of moment are you using ?

Comment: "moment-timezone": "^0.5.5"

Comment: Specifically '0.5.25'

Comment: Could you put your solution into plunker/jsfiddle? I can't replicate this.

Answer (score 1):

From your comment in the question:

> I'm in the Quatar timezone. The above code returns '2000-01-01T04:00:00' for me ...

This would only happen under one of the following conditions:

- Regardless of location, you are actually converting from UTC to Qatar's time zone:

  ```
  moment("2000-01-01T01:00:00Z").tz('Asia/Qatar').format('YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss')
  //=> "2000-01-01T04:00:00"
  ```
- You are in Qatar, and were just converting to local time:

  ```
  moment("2000-01-01T01:00:00Z").format('YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss')
  //=> "2000-01-01T04:00:00"
  ```
- You have loaded the scripts for moment and moment-timezone, but you have not loaded any time zone data.  In this case, you will get an error message in the debug console stating `Moment Timezone has no data for <zone name> ...`

  In this case, the time zone conversion cannot happen, and thus it behaves the same as the code in the previous condition above.

  Instead of loading `moment.timzone.js`, use one of the files that includes time zone data, such as `moment-timezone-with-data-10-year-range.js`.  See [these docs](https://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/use-it/).

I suspect it's the last one.